# equation for increasing probability

Tags: probability, likelihood

I'm looking for a stats equation.  He is an example

x = possibility % of life on a planet.

T1 = test that has a known probability.  Lets say, Does the planet have water. Yes = 20% probability the planet has life.

T2 = test that has a known probability, independent from test 1.  Lets say, Is the planet in the habitable range from a star, Yes = 10% probability that the planet has life.

Obviously if something test true for T1 and true for T2 than it has an increased possibility of having life on the planet.  As opposed to testing only true for one of them.

I'm looking for the statistical equation that proves this.  So I can have, what the probability for x would be given T1 and T2 are true.  knowing T1 and T2 probabilities.

Do it can't be Bayes' theorem this is why.
Here is a different example.

Lets say you want to diagnosis disease x.
You run 1 test.  Say a blood screen, it's 55% probability of being a True Positive.
Then you run test 2. Say a spinal tap, it too is 55% probability of being True Positive.

Neither one depends on the other.  Yet if you get 2 diagnosed your odds of being tested positive are increased, (right?)  There are multiple medical things tested this way.

So how do they calculate that?
It's the same question just worded differently.  But I do get the Bayes theorem, that is one is conditional on the other.  But these test neither one is conditional on the other.  Your results of testing 1 does not make testing 2 more likely.  and vice versa.  Yet combined they give a fuller picture.

Comment: I think you can try something like Bayes' theorem, if I am correctly understanding what you are trying to do. Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem

Comment: The amount of increase (or decrease!) of the probability depends on your theory of exoplanets.  All that probability theory can provide is mathematical bounds on the possibilities.  It's up to you to formulate the equation you're looking for, basing it either on theory or data.

Comment: In both of your examples there is strong chance of interaction. The habitable zone is associated with the correct conditions for water. Medical tests often have an underlying covariance due to measuring aspects of the same pathology.